# mysql agregate according to the scale

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to select data from a database which would be aggregated according to the scale. When I have the data below, then I want to aggregate the data from the column col2 in the range in col1 from one to three, from four to six, etc.

```
col1 |  col2
-----+----
1    |  34
2    |  43
3    |  75
4    |  23
5    |  62
6    |  33
...  |  ...
```

The result would be like this:

```
| SUM(col2)
+----
  152        - for values from 1 to 3
  118        - for values from 4 to 6
  ...        ...
```

I don't know how to write a one SQL select, that can return this data.
Thanks for your answers and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 3):

```sql
CREATE TABLE t (col1 integer, col2 integer);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1,34),(2,43),(3,75),(4,23),(5,62),(6,33);

SELECT ceil(col1/3) AS grp, min(col1) AS col1_from,
       max(col1) AS col1_till, sum(col2)
  FROM t
 GROUP BY ceil(col1/3);
```

Also on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19919/1).

Comment: @user1502291, is your question answered?